# Favorite Question: Receiving an inbox message when someone makes a new contribution

Tags: feature-request

If you could receive inbox message update when someone made a change to one of your favourite questions, would that be a feature request others would support?

Comment: It's a pretty popular one, to be honest. It's been on [Meta.SE for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox). It'd be really great to implement something like this in the future but I'm not sure where that lands in our priorities. :) We have a lot of stuff to work on that the community has been clamoring for for years. You can sort of see updates to your favorite questions. Using the star under the voting arrows to mark a question as a favorite, you can see any recent activity in the favorites tab on your profile.